# different actions using PHP for each forms handling in one page

Tags: php, forms

What kind of form action is the best to use with "post" method and PHP handling, if I want more forms in one page build and for each of them and after submit to display the number of points won by filling each form by user?

Comment: Can you put in an example of the forms? Sounds like you might need a hidden variable in each form to indicate which form it is.

Comment: <?php
      $DisplayForm['le1a1'] = True;
      if(isset($_POST['lek1a1'])){
        $DisplayForm ['le1a1']= False;
         echo "sucesfully";
echo "you won" .$ro071. “points”;
         if ($DisplayForm['le1a1']){
        ?>
    <form action="" id="le1a1"method= "post">
     <input type = "text" name="O071a11"> <br>
     <input type = "text" name="O071a12"><br>
     <input type = "text" name="O071a13"><br>
    <input type = "text" name="O071a14"><br>
    <input type = "submit" name="lek1a1" value="check">
   <input type="reset" name="reset">
    </form>
    
      <?php

Comment: some similar forms , each hidde after submit and display points user won filling it. Calculation of points would be added later when solves problem how to hide by submit, namely more forms and each hidden by its submit...Thanks Jacques if you have answer...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem is that you have multiple forms on a page, and you want each one to be hidden after the user submits it (and not reappear when another form is completed).

It would be better to do this on the server side by storing the state in the session (or perhaps a database). However if this security/usability issue is not important it is possible to implement on the client side:

When a form is not visible, you need to put a hidden input field in all the other forms with the name of the non-visible form. You should then check if this value is present in the PHP code and if so, continue to hide the form in your response.

Alternatively, you could store the form-hiding state in a query string and simply redirect the user when they submit.

Comment: yes hifkanotiks, you are right, user goes ahead only on new form , the old filled forms are hidden for him. Thanks that you recognized.